# Why can't I make an array of type NSLayoutConstraint?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode7

Basically, I am trying to reset some NSConstraints when the user taps a button.

**My constraint outlets:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstButtonHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var secondButtonheight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var thirdButtonHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

**Example action:**

```
@IBAction func firstButtonHeight(sender: UIButton) {
    firstButtonHeight.constant = 100
}
```

I thought I could put them into an array (below) and iterate through them *before* running `firstButtonHeight.constant = 100`:

```
var constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [firstButtonHeight, secondButtonheight, thirdButtonHeight]
for constraint in constraints {
    constraint.constant = 50 //Original constraint value
}
```

However, I get the error `Instance member 'firstButtonHeight' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'`. When did `firstButtonHeight` become a ViewController?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of all the other ten million Stack Overflow questions about this same error: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+instance+member+cannot+be+used+on+type

Comment: @matt so why answer it?  Vote to close it as a relevant dupe and move on instead of droning on about how this is a duplicate.

Comment: @JAL I _did_ vote to close it. But I had no _single_ canonical post to point to. Besides, the "drone" was my whole point: the OP should have searched first. Also, I have dupe hammer superpowers, so if I picked an actual duplicate, the question would simply have been closed, kaboom; I didn't want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

One major problem is that in your `constraints` initializer you mention the names of other instance variables. You can't do that, because at instance variable initialization time, the instance doesn't exist yet — it is what we are initializing!

You could solve this easily by moving the code into a function that runs *after* initialization time:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstButtonHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondButtonheight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var thirdButtonHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    func someFunction() {
        var constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [firstButtonHeight, secondButtonheight, thirdButtonHeight]
        for constraint in constraints {
            constraint.constant = 50 //Original constraint value
        }
    }
}
```

Look carefully at the difference between that and what you've been doing.

A common solution to the problem where you need to mention an instance variable in another instance variable's initializer is to declare the second instance variable `lazy`. Note that you *must* use `self` when you do this (and in general I would recommend always using it). Thus, this compiles at top level of your view controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstButtonHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var secondButtonheight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var thirdButtonHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
lazy var constraints : [NSLayoutConstraint] = [self.firstButtonHeight, self.secondButtonheight, self.thirdButtonHeight]
```

But the rest, the `for` loop, still needs to live inside a function body.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. But if I want to use `constraints` in multiple actions, then I need to recreate the array for every action or stuff it into another function?

Comment: No, I didn't say that. I explained why _your_ code was giving _that_ error. The correct procedure is to _declare_ `constraints` at the top level, but _initialize_ it later. For example, you could solve the problem simply by declaring it `lazy`. I'll add that to my answer.